# From Auto.arima to forecast in R

Tags: r

I don't quite understand the syntax of how `forecast()` applies external regressors in the `library(forecast)` in `R`.

My fit looks like this:

`fit <- auto.arima(Y,xreg=factors)`

where `Y` is a `timeSeries` object 100 x 1 and factors is a `timeSeries` object 100 x 5.

When I go to forecast, I apply...

`forecast(fit, h=horizon)`

And I get an error:

`Error in forecast.Arima(fit, h = horizon) : No regressors provided`

Does it want me to add back the xregressors from the fit?  I thought these were included in the `fit` object as `fit$xreg`.  Does that mean it's asking for future values of the xregressors, or that I should repeat the same values I used in the fit set?  The documentation doesn't cover the meaning of `xreg` in the forecast step.

I believe all this means I should use

`forecast(fit, h=horizon,xreg=factors)`

or

`forecast(fit, h=horizon,xreg=fit$xreg)`

Which gives the same results.  But I'm not sure whether the forecast step is interpreting the factors as future values, or appropriately as previous ones.  So,

1. Is this doing a forecast out of purely past values, as I expect?
2. Why do I have to specify the xreg values twice?  It doesn't run if I exclude them, so it doesn't behave like an option.

Comment: If you could post some code that could reproduce the problem it is much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I see what you mean, but my code is really just the two lines repeated above, `auto.arima()` and `forecast()`.  My question is about how the forecast function call is interpreting the external regressors.

Comment: still, I do not have your data (or some example data for that matter) that can reproduce the error message you get.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think you may not completely understand how the ARIMA model with regressors works.

When you forecast with a simple ARIMA model (without regressors), it simply uses past values of your time series to predict future values. In such a model, you could simply specify your horizon, and it would give you a forecast until that horizon.

When you use regressors to build an ARIMA model, you need to include *future values of the regressors* to forecast. For example, if you used temperature as a regressor, and you were predicting disease incidence, then you would need future values of temperature to predict disease incidence.

In fact, the documentation *does* talk about `xreg` specifically. look up `?forecast.Arima` and look at both the arguments `h` and `xreg`. You will see that If `xreg` is used, then `h` is ignored. Why? Because if your function uses `xreg`, then it *needs* them for forecasting.

So, in your code, `h` was simply ignored when you included `xreg`. Since you just used the values that you used to fit the model, it just gave you all the predictions for the same set of regressors *as if they were in the future*.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I did not understand this required future values, because these were beyond my information set.  I see how these options give me flexibility to externally forecast my regressor path with different assumptions.  I guess my assumption must have been that forecast() would give me a random walk future path. VAR() forecasting probably suits my needs better than external regressors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

related
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110589/arima-with-xreg-rebuilding-the-fitted-values-by-hand

I read that arima in R is borked
See Issue 3 and 4

https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/Rissues.htm

the xreg was suggested to derive the proper intercept.

I'm using real statistics for excel to figure out what is the actual constant.  I had a professor tell me you need to have a constant

These derive the same forecasts.  So it appears you can use xreg to get some descriptive information, but you would have to use the statsexchange link to manually derive from them.

```
f = auto.arima(lacondos[,1])

f$coef

g = Arima(lacondos[,1],c(t(matrix(arimaorder(f)))),include.constant=FALSE,xreg=1:length(lacondos[,1]))

g$coef
```