# In R, how to add an external variable to an ARIMA model?

Tags: r, statistics

Does anyone here know how I can specify additional external variables to an ARIMA model ?

In my case I am trying to make a volatility model and I would like to add the squared returns to model an ARCH.

The reason I am not using GARCH models, is that I am only interested in the volatility forecasts and the GARCH models present their errors on their returns which is not the subject of my study.

I would like to add an external variable and see the R^2 and p-values to see if the coefficient is statistically significant.

Comment: You should check the documentation: `?arima`. Specifically, look at the `xreg` argument. Also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606295/from-auto-arima-to-forecast-in-r/) for help forecasting. Finally, ARCH and GARCH are very field-specific models, which the general R audience may not be familiar with.

Comment: @nograpes: I am a student and tried to use R to do some homeworks. Is it valid to use arima and add the squared returns to model the volatility ? Will this give me an ARCH model ?

Comment: That really isn't an R question. I have no idea if it is valid or not. Perhaps it would be better asked on a statistical forum. A Google search turned up this [very extensive document on econometrics in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf), perhaps you should take a look. Finally, there is a `rgarch` package which probably does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is a very old question but for people like me who were wondering this you need to use cbind with xreg.

For Example:
Arima(X,order=c(3,1,3),xreg = cbind(ts1,ts2,ts3))

Each external time series should be the same length as the original.